# how to extract coordinates from postal code in swift through API?

Tags: ios, swift, location, latitude-longitude, geocode

I am stuck here in extracting latitude and longitude for a given postal code. can anyone please help me figuring out this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `CLGeocoder` method `geocodePostalAddress(_:completionHandler:)` to convert an address that contains just a postal code into a `CLLocation`.

See Apple's documentation on the [**CLGeocoder class reference**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder) for information on using it.